# Python : Division of unicode by unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I have to run the below part of a code, where Unicode is divided by a Unicode.

```
def updateUI(self):
    p = unicode(self.SpinB1.value())
    r = unicode(self.SpinB2.value())
    t = unicode(self.Combo1.currentText())
    t = t.split()
    q = t[0]

    amount = p * ((1 + (r / unicode(100)))**q)
    self.label5.setText(amount)
```

I am getting the below error : 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'unicode' and 'unicode''

What can I do to get this to work?

Comment: Why do you want your numbers in Unicode? Why not just use them as ints?

Comment: How exactly would you expect dividing strings, unicode or otherwise, to work?

Comment: Instead of using `unicode`, use `float` or `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't divide unicode types. Convert to ints or floats and then divide:

```
amount = int(p) * ((1 + (int(r) / 100))**int(q))
```